# Location based search for shops

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-maps

I have a big database of shops with their addresses and I want to provide location based search on top of that. For simplicity lets assume they are all in one city.

If someone searches for a shop in an area it should first show up all shops of that area followed by shops of nearby areas( in order of distance).

Here is the approach I could think of so far:

> 1. Created a table called "Places" which contains an exhaustive list of all locations where I want to provide the search.
> 2. Create another table "ShopAddress" where I store a shop id against its precise location. So shop s1 is in location Loc1.
> 3. I display search hints as the user types by pulling out data from "Places" table.
> 4. When a user selects a location say LOC1 I display s1.

Now the question is how do I show the nearby shops? For that I thought I would find out list of nearby places from Google and match them against places in my database.

So Loc1 is near to Loc2, Loc3 hence I also show up shops at Loc2 and LOC3.

I do not think this is the perfect way to do this? Anybody who has solved this problem could offer some suggestions please. I want to solve this problem using **ASP .NET MVC** and **jquery**.

Any answers please, need help to get started.

Comment: you store the longitude and lattitude of that particular place into database and used google maps api to get exact location

Comment: How do I find nearby locations but? Should I traverse through each entry and find the distance - that will be a performance hit. Also given that the nearby locations will be always same for a particular place...

Comment: @user2645830 define a set radius around point. If other locations lie within radius then it is nearby and display it. You could set the nearby locations, but what if you add new locations. Then you would have to update these, nearby locations array, aswell as other stuff.